# Center of multiple points/coordinates/mass

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, coordinates

This question [Center of mass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192099/how-to-divide-with-tikz-calc-to-find-center-of-mass) was answered in different ways. If we have coordinates (m1), (m2), (m3), (m4) one more way is to write

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=24cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);

\coordinate (m1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (m2) at (7,1);
\coordinate (m3) at (7,4);
\coordinate (m4) at (1,4);

% foreach \x in {1,2,3,4} ?

\draw (m1) circle (3pt);
\draw (m2) circle (3pt);
\draw (m3) circle (3pt);
\draw (m4) circle (3pt);

\draw [fill] ($($($ (m1)!1/2!(m2) $) !1/3! (m3)$) !1/4! (m4)$) circle (5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

because   ((1/2 (m1 + m2)) 2/3 + 1/3 m3) 3/4 + 1/4 m4 = 1/4 sum_{i=1}^4 mi.

How the tikz code above can be written with a `foreach` statement, especially if there are some more points?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question can be answered using the `calc` package and the `\foreach` loop, by additionally observing where macros will be expanded in time (below, `(\p)` with `\p`=`1,1` works, whereas `\p` with `\p`=`(1,1)` does not).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);
  \coordinate (m) at (0,0);
  \foreach \p [count = \n] in {{1,1}, {7,1}, {7,4}, {1,4}}
    {\draw (\p) circle (3pt);
     \coordinate (m) at ($(m)+(\p)$);
    }
  \coordinate (m) at ($1/\n*(m)$);
  \draw[fill] (m) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead of summing up the coordinates and scaling the sum in the end it is also possible to use the partway operator, which scales in each step.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);
  \coordinate (m) at (0,0);
  \foreach \p [count = \n] in {{1,1}, {7,1}, {7,4}, {1,4}}
    {\draw (\p) circle (3pt);
     \coordinate (m) at ($(m)!1/\n!(\p)$);
    }
  \draw[fill] (m) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have all the indegredients, but to draw the right clues from them is not so easy  :-). I understand your code. Just for fun: Is there a `foreach` solution to generate this nested code line with the partway syntax?

Comment: @Nik Yes, the partway syntax can also be iterated, see the extended answer.

Comment: Thank you, once more. I was just trying to generate exactly your second code. With this code one can show how the center is moving with every new added point.

Comment: @Nik This is also possible with the first version. Who cares if you have to iterate over all masses every time you add a point?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The idea was, that even if you have lost the first say 10 data and have kept only the average of them, nevertheless you can build with this average a new average (as long as you know that the first average was build out of 10 data). Nothing more.

Comment: @Nik The partway approach, avoiding recalculation, is certainly more elegant.

Comment: You could use `\foreach \p [count = \n] in` and this does all the define, increment `\n` automatically within the loop.